# Android: "unable to add window token is not valid is your activity running?" in my SplashScreenActivity

Tags: android

I am new to android and now I am creating a app with **splash screen as a launcher activity**.

When I am trying to open the app it shows **unable to add window token is not valid is your activity running**.But if I open the app second time then it is working fine

My code is here:

public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

```
private String mSavedEmail;
private String mSavedPassword;
public static SplashScreenActivity sInstance = null;
private User mUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        SplashScreenActivity.sInstance = SplashScreenActivity.this;

    /* Initiate Crittercism */
        Crittercism.initialize(SplashScreenActivity.this, Const.CRITTERCISM_APP_ID);


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                new CouchDB();
            }
        }).start();


        // new UsersManagement();

        String language = SampleApp.getPreferences().getGuiLanguage();
        if (!language.equals("")) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        if (SampleApp.hasNetworkConnection()) {

            if (checkIfUserSignIn()) {
                boolean isLinked = false;
                mSavedEmail = SampleApp.getPreferences().getUserEmail();
                mSavedPassword = SampleApp.getPreferences().getUserPassword();
                if (mSavedPassword.equals("")) {
                    isLinked = true;
                    mSavedPassword = SampleApp.getPreferences().getUserLinkedPassword();
                }

                mUser = new User();

                CouchDB.authAsync(mSavedEmail, mSavedPassword, isLinked, new AuthListener(), SplashScreenActivity.this, false);
            } else {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                                SignInActivity.class));
                        //finish();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                            SignInActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Const.SIGN_IN, true);
                    SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    Log.v("sample", "SplashScreenActivity starts SignInActivity");

                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                            getString(R.string.no_internet_connection),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

private boolean checkIfUserSignIn() {
    boolean isSessionSaved = false;
    Preferences prefs = LasteekApp.getPreferences();
    if (prefs.getUserEmail() == null 
            || (prefs.getUserPassword() == null && prefs.getUserLinkedPassword() == null)) {
        isSessionSaved = false;
    } else if (prefs.getUserEmail().equals("")
            && (prefs.getUserPassword() != null && prefs.getUserPassword().equals(""))) {
        isSessionSaved = false;
    }
    else if (prefs.getUserEmail().equals("")
            && (prefs.getUserLinkedPassword() != null && prefs.getUserLinkedPassword().equals(""))) {
        isSessionSaved = false;         
    }
    else {
        isSessionSaved = true;
    }
    return isSessionSaved;
}

private void signIn(User u) {

    UsersManagement.setLoginUser(u);
    UsersManagement.setToUser(u);
    UsersManagement.setToGroup(null);

    Log.d("User", "GetEmail "+u.getEmail());

    boolean openPushNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(
            Const.PUSH_INTENT, false);

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
            MyProfileActivity.class);
    if (openPushNotification)  {
        intent = getIntent();
        intent.setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                MyProfileActivity.class);
    }

    //parse URI hookup://user/[ime korisnika] and hookup://group/[ime grupe]
    Uri userUri = getIntent().getData();
    //If opened from link
    if (userUri != null) {
            String scheme = userUri.getScheme();        // "hookup"
            String host = userUri.getHost();        // "user" or "group"
            if (host.equals("user")) {
                    List<String> params = userUri.getPathSegments();
                    String userName = params.get(0);    // "ime korisnika"
                    intent.putExtra(Const.USER_URI_INTENT, true);
                    intent.putExtra(Const.USER_URI_NAME, userName);
            } else if (host.equals("group")) {
                    List<String> params = userUri.getPathSegments();
                    String groupName = params.get(0);   // "ime grupe"
                    intent.putExtra(Const.GROUP_URI_INTENT, true);
                    intent.putExtra(Const.GROUP_URI_NAME, groupName);
            }
    }

    intent.putExtra(Const.SIGN_IN, true);

    try{
        if(u.getName().toString().equals("")||u.getName().toString()==null){
            Log.v("lasteek", "SplashScreenActivity starts EditProfileActivity 1");
            intent.putExtra(Const.NEWLY_SIGNED_UP, true);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (u.getTitlePosition().toString().equals("")||u.getTitlePosition().toString()==null) {
            Log.v("sample", "SplashScreenActivity starts EditProfileActivity 2");
            intent.putExtra(Const.NEWLY_SIGNED_UP, true);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (u.getFunction()==null) {
            Log.v("sample", "SplashScreenActivity starts EditProfileActivity 3");
            intent.putExtra(Const.NEWLY_SIGNED_UP, true);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (u.getIndustry()==null) {
            Log.v("sample", "SplashScreenActivity starts EditProfileActivity 4");
            intent.putExtra(Const.NEWLY_SIGNED_UP, true);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.v("sample", "SplashScreenActivity starts MyProfileActivity");
            SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Exception",e.toString());
    }

    //finish();
}

private void checkPassProtect (User user) {

    if (sample.getPreferences().getPasscodeProtect()) 
    {
        Intent passcode = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                PasscodeActivity.class);
        passcode.putExtra("protect", true);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivityForResult(passcode, 0);
    } 
    else
    {
        signIn(user);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        signIn(mUser);
    }
    else {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                SignInActivity.class));
        //finish();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private boolean authentificationOk(User user) {

    boolean authentificationOk = false;

    if (user.getEmail() != null && !user.getEmail().equals("")) {
        if (user.getEmail().equals(mSavedEmail)) {
            authentificationOk = true;
        }
    }
    return authentificationOk;
}

private class AuthListener implements ResultListener<String>
{
    @Override
    public void onResultsSucceded(String result) {
        boolean tokenOk = result.equals(Const.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
        mUser = UsersManagement.getLoginUser();
        if (tokenOk && mUser!=null) {
            if (authentificationOk(mUser)) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        checkPassProtect(mUser);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        } else {
            SideBarActivity.appLogout(false, false, true, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResultsFail() {
        SideBarActivity.appLogout(false, false, false, true);
    }
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        if (SharedData.runningActivities == 0) {
            // app enters foreground
        }
        SharedData.runningActivities++;
        Log.v("sample.activitymonitor", "SplashScreenActivity enters foreground");
        Log.v("sample.activitymonitor", "runningActivities=" + SharedData.runningActivities);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedData.runningActivities--;
    if (SharedData.runningActivities == 0) {
        // app goes to background
    }
    Log.v("sample.activitymonitor", "SplashScreenActivity enters background");
    Log.v("sample.activitymonitor", "runningActivities=" + SharedData.runningActivities);
}
```

}